# How to get the words that start with '#' in string using php?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this sentence

```
"My name's #jeff,what is thy name?"
```

And now i want to get `#jeff` from this sentence. 
I have tried this code

```
for ($i=0; $i <=substr_count($Text,'#'); $i++) { 
    $a=explode('#', $Text);
    echo $a[$i];
}
```

But it returns `#jeff,what is thy name?` which is not what my soul desires

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is simpler solution to do it. Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) that find target part of string using regex.

```
preg_match("/#\w+/", $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0]
```

Check result of code in [demo](https://3v4l.org/Qe2Pv)

If you want to get all matches string, use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) that find all matches.

```
preg_match_all("/#\w+/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: What if there are two '#'?I tried `echo $matches[$i];` but did not work.

Comment: Try: `var_dump($matches)` to see what the result looks like.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sentence:`#Save #thy #selves`. results:`array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "#Save" }`

Comment: `preg_match()` quits after finding its first match..

Comment: If string has multiple matches, use `preg_match_all()`. See https://3v4l.org/GPjkc

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would not capture the word with `#`, since a hashtag is only an identifier for your code to get the attached word.

```
$re = '/(?<!\S)#([A-Za-z_][\w_]*)/';
$str = "My name's #jeff,what #0is #thy name?";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches[0]); // #jeff, #thy
print_r($matches[1]); // jeff, thy
```

By the [rules](https://www.hashtags.org/featured/what-characters-can-a-hashtag-include/) of hashtags, it may not start with a digit but may contain them.

Comment: Note that `(?:^|\s)` can be replaced with `(?<!\S)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I really didn't think of using a negative lookbehind, good catch.